# Adding subview to uistackview not working on button click

Tags: ios, xamarin.ios, uistackview

I am adding a bunch of views to a stack view in my `ViewDidLoad`. At the end I am adding a "Load More" button which would repeat the code that works in the `ViewDidLoad` - adding more arranged subviews. But I can't see any of the views on the screen. Any help is much appreciated.

```
public override void ViewDidLoad()
{
  stackView.AddArrangedSubview(view1);
  stackView.AddArrangedSubview.(view2);
  stackView.AddArrangedSubview.(button);
  button.TouchUpInside += (object sender, EventArgs e) =>
  {
    stackView.AddArrangedSubview(view1);
    stackView.AddArrangedSubview.(view2);
}
```

Comment: I think you need to create new instances of view1 and view2 in your button click event. e.g `stackView.AddArrangedSubView(new View1());`

Comment: view1 and view2 are already in your StackView so cannot be added again.

Comment: First, check if the view you add are not null. Second, check after click the button how many vieww your stackview contains. Could you provide us where you create your view1 and view2 instance please ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Here is my sample code base on yours:

**Notes:** I set my stackview with :

> Distribution set to "Fill equality" and Alignement set to "Fill"

```
public override void ViewDidLoad()
{
    base.ViewDidLoad();
    // Perform any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    AddViewsInStackView(); // Add views first time in the stackview
    AddButtonInStackView(); // Add the "Add button" first time in the stackview
}

private void AddViewsInStackView()
{
    // Create 2 views and add them to the stackview
    var view1 = new UIView { BackgroundColor = UIColor.Red };
    var view2 = new UIView { BackgroundColor = UIColor.Green };

    stackView.AddArrangedSubview(view1);
    stackView.AddArrangedSubview(view2);
}

private void AddButtonInStackView()
{
    // create the "Add button" 
    var button = new UIButton(UIButtonType.Custom);
    button.SetTitle("Add", UIControlState.Normal);
    button.SetTitleColor(UIColor.Blue, UIControlState.Normal);

    button.TouchUpInside += (sender, e) => AddSupplementaryViews();
    stackView.AddArrangedSubview(button); // Add the "Add button" in the stackview
}

private void AddSupplementaryViews()
{
    if (stackView.ArrangedSubviews.Any())
    {
        // Fetch the "Add button" then remove them
        var addButton = stackView.ArrangedSubviews.Last();
        stackView.RemoveArrangedSubview(addButton); // This remove the view from the stackview
        addButton.RemoveFromSuperview(); // This remove the view from the hierarchy

        AddViewsInStackView(); // Add new views
        AddButtonInStackView(); // Add it again so it will be the last one every time
    }
}
```

Comment: thats pretty much what I am trying to do. The view are being added to the stack view as well. Its just not updated on the screen immediately. When I moved to another view and then came back to this view I could see the added subviews. So I am guessing I need to do something to refresh the view after adding the subviews.

Comment: Could you please provide your code where you add your views in the stackview please ? Also: are you sure you are not add these views from a background thread ?

Answer (score 0):

I am new to Swift but had encountered a similar problem when adding a button with action in a stackview.

Though I am using a #selector() , I think my problem was that I did not add @objc with my button variable. This way, somehow the target action was not resolved by the compiler probably ( I am not sure).

Please try

> @objc lazy var button = new UIButton(UIButtonType.Custom);

Hopefully, it will help.

Thanks,
Aditya

Comment: this is not a right way to post your answer https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: Changed it, hope this helps